# Moving a finger out from a UIButton not de-selecting the button

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uibutton

I am adding a UIButton in my view & I want the button to be deselected whenever user moves its finger out of the button. This is working fine when i touch & move the finger up but not on the bottom. Is there is something missing in my code:

My Button's frame is - `{{7, 8}, {260, 40}}`

```
self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:150.0/255.0 green:150.0/255.0 blue:150.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
self.myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize16];
self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
[self.myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x + 7, self.bounds.origin.y + 8, self.bounds.size.width - 10, 40)];
[self.myButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pressed.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12.0 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.myButton addTarget:nil action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self addSubview:self.myButton];
```

Another thing is that i am implementing touchesBegan/touchesEnded methods on my UIView class.

Comment: One noticable thing is that when I reduce the width of the my button to 30 px, I got the desired results. But button looks very small. Is this a UIKit default behavior and can this be override somehow?

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of image that you are using? Normal.png & Pressed.png size's? Based on its size update your button frame:

Suppose if Normal.png is of `{40, 40}` set your button width & height as

```
self.myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(7, 8, 40, 40)];
```

now run the app and check.

Comment: what did you write in touches began? If possible mail me your code, I will debug it.